# "A linear operator $f$ is continuous if $f(V)$ is bounded for some neighborhood $V$ of $0$."

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Topological_structure)

> a linear operator $f$ between two topological vector spaces is continuous if $f(V)$ is bounded for some
> neighborhood $V$ of $0$.

1. I wonder why it is true?

   If I understand correctly, "$f(V)$ is bounded
   for some neighborhood $V$ of $0$" is same as saying $f$ is locally bounded?
2. I saw elsewhere that for a linear operator between two TVSes,
   continuity implies mapping bounded subsets to bounded subsets.

   So if $f$ is linear mapping between two TVSes, does "$f(V)$ is bounded
   for some neighborhood $V$ of $0$" imply that $f$ maps bounded subsets to
   bounded subsets?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Why don't you read Rudin's functional analysis? Everything you asking about TVS last time is explained there.

Comment: @Norbert: okay!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a linear mapping between two TVS with the property that  $f(V)$  is bounded for some neighbourhood $V$ of $0$. It suffices to show that $f$ is continuous at $0$, let $U$ be a neighbourhood of $0$ at $Y$. By definition of being bounded there is a $t$ so that $f(V)\subseteq t\cdot U$ this implies $\frac 1 t\cdot f(V)\subseteq U$. Since $\frac 1  t\cdot f(V)=f(\frac 1 t \cdot V)$ and $\frac 1 t \cdot V$ is open we obtain that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question: yes, a continuous function will map bounded sets to bounded sets. Assume  $f:X\to Y$ has a neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ with $f(V)$ bounded. If $A\subset X$ is bounded, there exists a number $t$ with $tA\subset V$. Then $tf(A)=f(tA)\subset f(V)$. Now fix any neighbourhood of $0$ in $Y$, say $W$. Since $f(V)$ is bounded, there exists $s$ with $s f(V)\subset W$. Then
$$
 st f(A) = s f(tA) \subset s f(V)\subset W.
$$
We conclude that $f(A)$ is bounded.

Comment: This might be too late. But I don't think this proof is correct. Because for a general cts linear operator $f: X\to Y$, it's not guaranteed $f$ is bounded on some neighborhood of the origin. To show a cts $f$ maps bdd sets to bdd sets, it's enough to use the fact that preimage of neighborhoods in Y are neighborhoods in X, and that neighborhoods are absorbing.

Comment: *Proof.* Suppose $f: X\to Y$ is cts. Let $A\subset X$ be bdd. Then, for every neighborhood $W\ni 0_Y$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}(W)\ni 0_X$ is a neighborhood in $X$. Then there exists $t>0$ s.t. $t A\subset  f^{-1}(W)$, and so $t f(A)=f(tA)\subset f\left(f^{-1}(W)\right)=W$. Since $W$ is arbitrary, $f(A)$ is then a bdd set in $Y$. $\square$

Comment: Fair enough. I think (who knows, it was 11 years ago) that I was trying to answer 'does "$f(V)$  is bounded for some neighborhood $V$  of $0$" imply that $f$ maps bounded subsets to bounded subsets?" '