# Bounded linear functionals on TVS and continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory, topological-vector-spaces

I have a potentially silly confusion over continuous linear functionals over topological vector spaces. Many sources say a linear functional $f: X\to \mathbb{F}$, where $X$ is a general topological vector space over $\mathbb{F}$, is continuous *iff* $f$ is bounded on *some* neighborhood of $0_X$. See, eg., Theorem 1.18 of Rudin's *Functional analysis (1991)*.

My question is: shouldn't $f$ be bounded on *every* neighborhood of $0_X$, for it to be continuous? Why only *some* is enough?

I know, when a subset $A\subset X$ of a TVS is defined as *bounded*, it is defined such that, for *every* open neighborhood $U\ni0$ of the origin, there exists $\epsilon_U>0$ s.t. $\epsilon_U A\subset U$. Here *every* open neighborhood is needed. So why can we get away with only *some* neighborhoods, when it comes to the continuity of linear functionals?

Does the same conclusion hold for linear operators?

Hope it makes sense. Thanks in advance.

**Update (self-answer):**

After some searching/thinking, it appears I inherently confused neighborhoods with *bounded* neighborhoods when asking this question. For general TVS, neighborhoods are never bounded, unless the space is (pseudo)metrizable. So, a linear operator/functional being bounded over *some* neighborhood $U$ of the origin already guarantees it is bounded over *all* bounded sets containing the origin. Because, *bounded* sets can be absorbed by *every* neighborhood of the origin, in particular, by $U$. It is also easy to prove such a linear operator/functional is cts.

For linear functionals, the converse is also true. If $f: X\to \mathbb{F}$ is continuous, then $\text{Ker}(f)$ is closed. If $f(X)=\{0\}$. It is obviously bounded everywhere. If $f(x)\neq 0$ for some $x\in X\setminus \{0_X\}$, then $\text{Ker}(f)$ is a closed *proper* subspace. Hence it cannot be dense. Then there exists an open neighborhood $V_x\ni x$ such that $V_x\cap \text{Ker}(f)=\emptyset$. In a TVS, every neighborhood of the origin contains a *balanced* neighborhood. So there is a balanced $V_x'-x\subset V_x-x$ containing $0_X$. So the image $f(V_x'-x)\subset \mathbb{F}$ is balanced and cannot be $\mathbb{F}$. Hence it is bounded.

But the converse doesn't always hold for linear operators between TVS. CTS linear operators can be unbounded over every neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes and no, as my confusion is about the difference between neighborhoods and *bounded* sets.

Comment: You seem to be perfectly aware of this difference, so what point precisely don't you understand when  reading the proposed duplicate?

Comment: @AnneBauval I didn't realize it's wrong to assume neighborhoods were bounded when posting this question or reading through the linked answers. I didn't even realize I was assuming it. So I didn't at all realize continuous operators are "bounded on *some*  neighborhood" and "map *every* bounded set to a bounded set" are two different propositions.

Comment: But *now*, the proposed duplicate answers your question, doesn't it?

Comment: @AnneBauval I'll wait for a few days. If no one comes and points out there are more misunderstandings in my question/answer, I'll close it.

Comment: Technically, I believe you cannot "close" it. You can only agree (in comments, or by voting if you have enough reputation) that it should be closed as a duplicate, your "Update self-answer" being but a reformulation of [the accepted answer over there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113893/386889).